# How create create effect rowspan in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, html-table

I need to create a table with the first column that has a particular `rowspan`.

The result that I want is like  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan) in detail I want the all row in the first column together. This is the code .html:

```
    //This row all toogether in one td
    <tr *ngFor="let count of listCount">
      <ng-container *ngIf="check()">
        <td rowspan="?"....>
        <td>..
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
```

The problem is that:

1. I don't know `rowspan` which is its value

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first column to span over the complete rows, you'll have to:

1. Use `rowspan="listCount.length"`.
2. But just the first column. To get whether the column is first, you can use `let first = first` in `*ngFor`.
3. Since this `rowspan` count will be dynamic, you'll have to use the Attribute Binding Syntax(`[attr.rowspan]="listCount.length"`).

Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let count of listCount; let first = first">
  <ng-container *ngIf="check()">
    <td *ngIf="first" [attr.rowspan]="listCount.length" ....>
    <td>..
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-rowspan-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your column to fill the whole table, you have to set `rowspan` attribute to equal rows count.
For conveniance, you can use `Angular` [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) `first` local variable to check the first row.
Here is a [stackblitz demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sasensi-rowspan) of the solution.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let i of rows; let isFirstRow = first">
        <!-- only display first column if it is the first row and set rowspan attribute -->
        <td *ngIf="isFirstRow" [attr.rowspan]="rows.length">Column 1</td>
        <td>Row {{i}}, column 2</td>
        <td>Row {{i}}, column 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
  styles: [`
    td {
      padding: 15px;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent
{
  rows = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[attr.rowspan]` and you can render all `td` by looping over `columns`(create a collection of columns) as well, and as you want you can apply `rowspan` to `first` column only. *Not completely sure what `*ngIf="check()"` is :(*

```
<tr *ngFor="let count of listCount">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns;let first = first; let last = last;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="check()">
        <td [attr.rowspan]="first ? 2: 1"....>
        <td>..
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```